# Using a jquery slider to display leaflet circle markers?

Tags: jquery, maps, leaflet

[EDIT] I've modified this question to reflect the current status of my problem.

I'm working on visualizing some spatial data that varies over time. I'm using Leaflet and I have the data in a GeoJSON. I'd like to have my map include a slider that enables the user to dynamically display markers based on time.

[EDIT] <s>I've tried to work with [this](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider) implementation. However, this only displays standard Leaflet markers and I need to be able to display circle markers that can be dynamically styled based on properties specified within the geojson.</s>

Styling the geojson and converting to leaflet circle markers works as expected using the following code:

```
var geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
style: myStyle,
onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng)
}   
})
```

With `myStyle` and `onEachFeature` handling the conversion to L.circleMarker and generating tooltips.

However, the issue I'm now dealing with is that the resulting slider adds each feature one at a time rather than as a group. Currently I have a geojson with approx. 600 features and 4 distinct time points (e.g. subgroups of 150 features that each have the same time stamp). What I want is for each group of 150 to be added simultaneously. Currently the slider iterates over each feature in the geojson and adds them one at a time.

Here is the code for the slider from Dennis Wilhelm's [LeafletSlider](https://github.com/dwilhelm89/LeafletSlider/blob/master/SliderControl.js) that I am using:

```
startSlider: function () {
        options = this.options;
        $("#leaflet-slider").slider({
            value: options.minValue + 1,
            min: options.minValue,
            max: options.maxValue +1,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (e, ui) {
                if(!!options.markers[ui.value]) {
                if(options.markers[ui.value]) $('#slider-timestamp').html(options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties.time.substr(0, 16));

                for (var i = options.minValue; i < ui.value ; i++) {
                    if(options.markers[i]) map.addLayer(options.markers[i]);
                }
                for (var i = ui.value; i <= options.maxValue; i++) {
                    if(options.markers[i]) map.removeLayer(options.markers[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    map.addLayer(options.markers[options.minValue]);
}
```

What is unclear to me is if I need to modify this slider function to place these features in a feature group and if so, how to do so. I'm relatively new to javascript, so if someone can point me to some useful starting points, I would be most appreciative.

Comment: How about a jsFiddle for those of us that are A/V impaired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nice to see that someone is actually using my Slider.
Sadly, I only found out about this question now.
However, if this question is still unsolved, maybe this can help:

It is possible to define a number of steps which will be performed at once.
So if you know the number of features you want to show when dragging the slider one step further, you can simplydefine this number within the slider properties.

E.g.

```
startSlider: function () {
    options = this.options;
    $("#leaflet-slider").slider({
        value: options.minValue + 1,
        min: options.minValue,
        max: options.maxValue +1,
        step: 500,
        slide: function (e, ui) {
            if(!!options.markers[ui.value]) {
            if(options.markers[ui.value]) $('#slider-timestamp').html(options.markers[ui.value].feature.properties.time.substr(0, 16));

            for (var i = options.minValue; i < ui.value ; i++) {
                if(options.markers[i]) map.addLayer(options.markers[i]);
            }
            for (var i = ui.value; i <= options.maxValue; i++) {
                if(options.markers[i]) map.removeLayer(options.markers[i]);
            }
        }
    }
});
map.addLayer(options.markers[options.minValue]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `html` file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready( function () {
var circle = L.circle([51.508, -0.11], 500, {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map);
});
</script>
```

And change to coordinates with your GeoJSON data.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I am trying to display the data using the L.circleMarker functionality which allows me to dynamically style the circle based on the geojson properties. The issue I'm having is with the jquery part of implementing the slider using L.circleMarker.

Comment: can you post the jqury part?

Comment: Right now, no. I am new to jquery and am not exactly sure where to begin. I've figured out how to create a slider, however, I can't figure out how to use what it produces to subset the geojson that I have loaded.

Comment: Thanks. This helped. I've modified the question to better reflect where I'm stuck.